# "Incorrect string value" when inserting non-ASCII into MySQL database using ADODB in MS Access (VBA), but retry works

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, adodb, non-ascii-characters

After finding a [bug in MySQL ODBC 5.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531411/output-parameter-of-mysql-stored-procedures-via-adodb-in-ms-access-vba-correct), I have another problem which also happens using MySQL ODBC 5.3.4.

I have an MS Access application (Office 2016 ProPlus 32-bit) that uses ADODB with MySQL ODBC (5.3.4 32-bit) to interface to a local MySQL database server (5.7.16 64-bit) on a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit computer. Inserting non-ASCII characters in the MySQL database fails with the error "Incorrect string value" but if I try the same statement again, the SQL statement is correctly executed and the correct value is inserted into the database table!

To isolate the problem, I created the following table:

```
  CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

And a test MS Access database containing the following VBA code (and a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 library):

```
  Public Function dbTestIt2() as Long

  Dim dbConn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim dbCmd As New ADODB.Command
  Dim dbParams As New ADODB.Parameter
  Dim l As Long

      dbConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};option=3;database=xxx;user=yyy;password=zzz;"
      dbConn.Open
      With dbCmd
          .ActiveConnection = dbConn
          .CommandType = adCmdText
          .CommandText = " INSERT INTO test2 (name) VALUES (?);"
          dbParams.Type = adVarChar
          dbParams.Size = 100
          dbParams.Value = "abcdèfgh"
          dbParams.Direction = adParamInput
          .Parameters.Append dbParams
          .Execute l, , adExecuteNoRecords
      End With
      dbConn.Close

      dbTestIt2 = l

  End Function
```

Relevant lines in my.ini:

```
  [client]
  default-character-set=utf8mb4
  [mysql]
  default-character-set=utf8mb4
  [mysqld]
  character-set-server=utf8mb4
  collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here are the test results:

1. Execution stops at the .Execute statement with the error 80004005: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.16-log]Incorrect string value: '\xE8gh' for column 'name' at row 1;
2. If I continue debugging (F8), the SQL statement is correctly executed and the correct value is inserted into the database table;
3. If I use the "ANSI" ODBC driver instead of the "Unicode" driver, this test succeeds the first time, but then more complex (e.g. Chinese) non-ASCII characters get replaced by question marks;
4. I believe that VBA internally uses Unicode but MySQL [does not support UTF16 for clients](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) and specifying "charset=utf8mb4" in the ODBC connection string or execute "SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4" first does not help and "SET NAMES utf8mb4" is not supported;
5. If I use INSERT IGNORE instead of INSERT, the first execution seems to succeed, but the value is actually truncated at the "è" (so only "abcd" is inserted);
6. It also happens with MySQL ODBC 5.3.6

Am I doing anything wrong or is this another bug in the MySQL ODBC driver?

Comment: Try `dbParams.Type = adVarWChar` instead of `dbParams.Type = adVarChar`.

Comment: @GordThompson: REALLY? just one letter?! You saved my day/week/month! I was trying all sorts of stuff like character-set-client-handshake=FALSE because I thought maybe the initial handshake failed. If you add your comment as an answer, I can select it as the best answer and maybe we can help some poor sod who has been struggling for weeks like me. #ifeelstupid

Comment: But it is still weird that it succeeds on the second try (I checked but the value of the dbParams.Type is not automatically modified).

Comment: And I am not sure anymore about the absence of UTF16 support for client character sets. I have specified "charset=utf16" in the connection string now and it is accepted, but does make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement ...

```vbs
dbParams.Type = adVarChar
```

... is telling the ADODB.Parameter object that its value will be a string of single-byte characters. Those single-byte characters will be passed to the ODBC driver, which will in turn pass them to the MySQL database engine. If the database engine is expecting UTF-8 characters then an error will occur because `0xE8` (`è` in many "latin-1"-type code pages like Windows-1252) is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence.

Changing the above statement to ...

```vbs
dbParams.Type = adVarWChar
```

... tells the ADODB.Parameter object that its value will be a string of multi-byte ("Wide") characters. When assigning the value using a VBA string literal ...

```vbs
dbParams.Value = "dèf"
```

... ADODB will convert the string from its single-byte representation (based on the current Windows locale) to Unicode, and pass that to the ODBC driver. The ODBC driver is able to "repackage" the string from raw Unicode (`U+0064 U+00E8 U+0066`) into UTF-8 encoding (`0x64 0xC3 0xA8 0x66`) and pass that to the database engine.